# Searching sorted data obtained by pandas.read_fwf

Tags: python, pandas, search

I have a memory data table obtained using pandas.read_fwf, the data is ordered in an Ascending way (I am referring to the Virtual column which i am interested in for searching) the data is not small it is about 300,000 rows

[Data sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w3lw2.png)

I would like to ask about the most efficient way to search such data considering the fact that they are sorted, I am interested in searching for a frame between two values, and keep in mind that i am basically searching in the values of a column (rows).

I looked into **bisect** and pandas.Series.**searchsorted**
but I figured that I might need to apply some data transpose in order to use them and thought that maybe there exist an easier way, thus im asking.

Thanks

Comment: If you need to search the data multiple times you would benefit from some kind of index, otherwise you could have a look at the sorted containers library, or possibly a binary search might help

Comment: As @kezzos has already said - use your "search" column as an index: `df.set_index('Virtual', inplace=True)` or set it when reading FWF file: `df = pd.read_fwf(..., index_col='Virtual')`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a mask? Even though it doesn't take sorting into account I feel like the performance would be fast enough.

```
df = df[(df[col] > val1) & (df[col] < val2)]
```

Otherwise here is a solution like you are looking for (assuming your df is sorted by column `col` in ascending order):

```
vals = df[col].iteritems()
val1 = # lower value
val2 = # upper value

for i in range(len(df)):
    val = next(vals)[1]
    if val > val1:
        i1 = i
        break

for i in range(i, len(df)):
    val = next(vals)[1]
    if val < val1:
        i2 = i
        break

df = df.iloc[i1:i2]
```

Comment: If you needed to do this many times the performance of these methods would not be good